# JSF best strategy to populate datatable

Tags: sql, jsf, jsf-2

I'm fairly new to JSF, and to coding itself. I'm working with JSF for 9 months now, and I noticed two ways of populating data tables:
-when pagination link is clicked, then new query is executed with given first and last record to show from results
-when user loads page query is executed and records are store in bean, so when pagination link is clicked, there is no query only giving records from stored result list (primefaces)

And here is my question :
**Witch way is better?**
I assume that second way need more memory, but it's used by primefaces, so I'm not sure that this is 'the right way'
First way need less memory - it gets only records needed to show, but isn't it to slow?

PS - BalusC - I hope you will take part in this discussion, since I see your answers very helpful, and explanatory:)

Comment: It depends on the case. On the client side, eager loading is ok with small quantity of data, but lazy loading is much better when dealing with big quantity of data.  On the server side, if you want to save some memory, request the needed data from the db on every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally when it comes to populating and managing a datatable. I feel the `lazy-loading` is the best practice. This is not a `JSF` specific way of loading the data, however; a few component libraries make it easy to implement (`Primefaces`, `Icefaces`, etc...).

`Lazy-loading` will help maintain large amounts of data, making sure the your page doesn't hang up and will keep a smooth user experience.

- [Primefaces LazyDataModel](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html)
- [Icefaces datatable(Already implemented)](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v3_latest/ace/tld/ace/dataTable.html)
- [Rich-faces Lazy Loading](http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/02/lazy-loading-of-tables-in-jsf-working-with-large-amount-of-data/)

Comment: So far I had 'pleasure' of working with Primefaces, and if you ask me, I'm not going to repeat that mistake. Lazy-loading is one thing, but rest of PF is just wrong.

Comment: @LuciusSnow Sometimes the ease of development comes with a heavy price on the performance side. Can you point out what's wrong with PF ?

Comment: sorry for not responding sooner -with PF everything works strange. just from top of my head - p:dialog and @ViewScoped is not working, and it's very irritating. plus it's slow and needs to much resources. While working with PF and pure JSF I noticed, that PF tends to behave strangely and not logical, while JSF is completely predictable - it works by the book, and that's what I need in my projects.